# Responsive nav bar not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I trying out Bootstrap for the first time and I based my code on their example here:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html

I basically copied the main content html code, but in my version the responsive nav bar does not work, in that when I click the 'hamburger button' the nav elements do not appear.

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My bootstrap files are from the Bootstrap customize site. I included everything in the build including responsive navbar.

Where am I going wrong.

Thanks everyone.

**UPDATE**

I removed my main.css file so no conflict there. I tried again downloading bootstrap from the customize page with everything ticked: twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html and still get the same problem. The css file it gives me is just called bootstrap.css not bootstrap-combined.css. Is there a problem with bootstraps customize page??

Comment: Is it definitely the bootstrap-responsive.css file you're using?

Comment: The file is just called bootstrap.css it's downloaded from the customize bootstrap page with responsive ticked (in fact everything ticked).

Comment: Are you still working on this Jamie?

Comment: I got it fixed now. The problem, interestingly, was that I was using the online Cloud9 IDE and for some reason Cloud9 was not serving any JS files. I tred again in a few hours, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/4XEnD/

I took your exact html and I'm using CDN versions of the CSS and JS -- everything looks good to me.

```
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Double check that you are using the responsive bootstrap CSS, that the Bootstrap js file is being loaded and that there isn't something in your main.css that is causing a conflict.

Good luck!

Comment: I removed my main.css file so no conflict there. I tried again downloading bootstrap from the customize page with everthing ticked:  http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html and still get the same problem. The css file it gives me is just called bootstrap.css not bootstrap-combined.css. Is there a problem with bootstraps customize page??

Comment: I just made another fork using the css file from the customise page you are using: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/tBKMj/ ... everything still looks good, so that's not the cause. The problem may be with your js file not being loaded. Double check your path or try using the CDN link above.